# Converting pressures to masses

Tags: pressure, mass, dimensional-analysis

I read that 2 mbar of atmospheric methane = 1 x 10^13 tons, but how is this calculated? I have looked for information but can only find this for converting pressure to kgs-of-force/cm^2.

Is atomic-weight involved here, as the difference between 2 mbar methane and the same quantity of carbon dioxide doesn't seem to reflect the factor of 2.2 difference in atomic-mass...

Comment: Where did you read that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So pressure is force divided by area and force is mass times acceleration:
$$P=\frac{F}{A}=\frac{ma}{A}$$
We can solve for mass:
$$m=\frac{PA}{a}$$
The pressure was 2 mbar, the area of the earth is around 500 T(m^2), and the acceleration due to gravity is roughly 10 m/s^2 so:

$$m=\frac{2\text{ mbar} \ 500 \ 10^{12} \text{ m}^2}{10\text{ m s}^{-2}} \frac{100 \text{ N m}^{-2}}{1 \text{ mbar}} = 1 \ 10^{16} \text{ kg}$$

The atomic mass does not matter. It will take fewer moles for a heavier molecule to make the same pressure, but the pressure is directly dependent on the mass itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and clarity of explanation. I followed this through and reached the 10^15 kg product of the upper half of your equation but, consistent with my name, failed to understand why dividing this 10^15 kg quantity by 10 m/s^2 yielded the increase to 10^16 kg (which is nevertheless the correct answer and the 10^13 tons that I mentioned).

Comment: @MathPoor it looks like you missed the factor of 100 conversion from mbar to N/m^2

Comment: Thanks again -- omitted it rather than missed it due to insufficient understanding; so, effectively, it's (10^15 kg/[10 m/2^2])100..?